# The href value of the Html anchor tag is rendering weird

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, master-pages

I want to assign dynamically the href value depending of certain things, I thing is important to mention that I have a Master Page, url routing and I am assigning absolute paths (like http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/...).

I've tried the following:

```
<a href="<%= DynamicURL%>">testing urls</a>
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="hpLink">this teset brouw</asp:HyperLink>
```

and in code behind

```
hpLink.NavigateUrl = "http://www.someurl.com/morepath/morethisngs";
```

I have also tried this

```
<a runat="server" id="aAccesories">Testing ...</a>
```

and in code behind I do this:

```
   aAccesorios.HRef = "http://www.someurl.com/morepath/morethisngs";
```

what ever I try when I see the html source code the links render like this:

```
http://localhost:10027/projectTest/\www.someurl.com/morepath/morethisngs
```

so I cant create absolute paths or absolute URLS, doesnt matter what I tried, this is weird isnt it? i adds the domain to the urls and then it removes the http:// then it adds the path I wanted

hope you can help me, thanks!

Comment: What webserver are you using? Is there any code that intercepts and silently alters any outgoing HTML?

Comment: I guess it is because I'm using url routing right?

Comment: No, URL routing is an API you call into, rather than something that modifies the page after it's been rendered. I'm surprised the `<%= DynamicURL %>` statement modified the URL - but are you sure the actual HTML isn't being modified and that you're actually looking at how the browser is interpreting it?